# Calculating Collective Count of departments on individual dates from a given date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following table

| Function | Department | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Const | Const 1 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-05 |
| Const | Const 2 | 2023-03-02 | 2023-03-03 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-02 | 2023-03-05 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-06 |
| Const | Const 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-07 |
| Const | Const 2 | 2023-03-02 | 2023-03-05 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-06 | 2023-03-09 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-08 |

I want to get per date the total count in each department. Both start date and end date and included in counting.

It would be nice to have an intermediate output as follows

| Function | Department | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-01 | 1 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-02 | 1 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-03 | 2 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-04 | 2 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-05 | 2 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-06 | 1 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-07 | 1 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-08 | 0 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-09 | 0 |
| Const | Const1 | 2023-03-10 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-01 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-02 | 2 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-03 | 2 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-04 | 1 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-05 | 1 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-06 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-07 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-08 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-09 | 0 |
| Const | Const2 | 2023-03-10 | 0 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-01 | 0 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-02 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-03 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-04 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-05 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-06 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-07 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-08 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-09 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 1 | 2023-03-10 | 0 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-01 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-02 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-03 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-04 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-05 | 2 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-06 | 2 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-07 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-08 | 1 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-09 | 0 |
| Mining | Mining 2 | 2023-03-10 | 0 |

The desired final output is a pandas df as follows

| Date | Const 1 | Const 2 | Mining 1 | Mining 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-03-02 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-03-03 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-03-04 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-03-05 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

dates = pd.date_range(df['Start Date'].min(), df['End Date'].max()) #get the complete dates in data set
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates})
final_df = final_df.set_index('Date')

departments = df['Department'].unique()

for department in departments:
    mask = (df['Department'] == department)
    department_counts = (df.loc[mask, 'Start Date'].value_counts() + df.loc[mask, 'End Date'].value_counts()).sort_index()
    final_df[department] = department_counts

final_df = final_df.fillna(0)
```